# Django deployment on windows vista

Tags: python, django, environment-variables

I have added C:\Python27\ for python and C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\bin\ for django to the path variable of environment settings.

But whenever I am running the command

```
django-admin.py startproject myapp
```

it is simply opening the django-admin.py file in notepad and not creating any custom django directory and file structure.

I am not able to start with my app development. I didn't faced any problem when I work on ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

try `python django-admin.py startproject myapp`

also make sure you have properly installed python ... it should auto-associate files ending in .py

Comment: it will not work because it will try to find django-admin.py in the current directory will try to execute that.

Comment: yes, python has been installed properly as it is working fine with tornado, excluding the dependency issues.